# python socket.gethostbyaddr() -- reduce timeout?

Tags: python, dns, ip-address

[`socket.gethostbyname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname) works great when its argument is a real hostname. But when it's a nonexistent host, I get a 3 second timeout followed by

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I don't mind the exception (it's appropriate), but is there any way to reduce the timeout?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution after going through this would be:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(5) #Default this is 30
socket.gethostbyname(your_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be impossible if Python uses system `gethostbyname()`. I'm not sure you really want this because you can receive false timeouts.

Once I had a similar problem, but from C++: I had to call the function for large number of names, so long timeout was a real pain. A solution was to call it from many threads in parallel, so while some of them was stuck waiting for timeout, all others were proceeding fine.

Comment: In this case I *do* really want a shorter timeout: I have access to an known good hostname to write data as a fallback (namely the server machine I am running the script on), and I allow an alternate hostname to be specified. If I can't verify the hostname in 100msec, I'm quite happy to assume it does not exist, and therefore I'll just write the data locally.

Comment: @Jason S: make this timeout yourself: run `gethostbyname()` in another thread and ignore its result if not completed within 100msec

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to threading but I tried implementing @Andriy Tylychko's suggestion of using threads.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def is_ip_connected(IP, timeout=2):
    ans = {"success": False}

    def _is_ip_connected(IP, ans):
        try:
            socket.gethostbyaddr(IP)
            ans["success"] = True
        except:
            pass

    time_thread = Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(timeout,))
    IP_thread = Thread(target=_is_ip_connected,  kwargs={"IP": IP, "ans": ans})

    time_thread.start()
    IP_thread.start()

    while time_thread.is_alive() and IP_thread.is_alive():
        pass

    return(ans["success"])


print(is_ip_connected(IP="192.168.1.202"))
```